# Wordpress admin bar not showing on frontend

Tags: wordpress

I've tried everything I have found but nothing helps me.

I've put

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

in header.php

and

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

I even tried:

1. Disable all plugins
2. Default WP theme
3. and etc.

Comment: Check your user profile if you have checked that option or is it disabled...

Comment: Don't worry, I already checked that.

Comment: If even the "default WP theme + all plugins disabled" doesn't work, it seems very very strange (even unbelievable to me)!

Comment: Yes. I tried to disable all plugins and change to default theme. Strange problem I know. That's the reason I wanna to share that with other peoples who might have same problem bacuse I've spent 2-3 hours on searching solution.

Comment: I could only recommend you to try to reinstall the WP (automatically or manually), but make sure you have a backup!!

Comment: That's ok solution when you on start of developing that site, but when you're not then you should rather think abou it before like I did :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you, but you can always reinstall the WP - this same task is happening every time you update your WP to the latest version (I hope you use the latest one? If yes, then on the same page there is a button Reinstall instead of Update)

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you :(

Comment: So updating/reinstalling resolved it? :-)

Comment: I didn't try that because this solved my problem so there is no need for that. But I'll try just for test when I'll have a little bit more time.

Comment: No need to try my proposal, but you wrote "this solved my problem"... could you please shortly describe what "this" exactly resolved your problem (if you did something), thanks! Anyway, I'm glad its fixed! :-)

Comment: Solution is in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21277191/1370370

Comment: Hah, I didn't realized that YOU answered this :-) Sorry, my oversight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution is to put** 
`show_admin_bar(true);` **on top of your functions.php file.**

EDIT fix:
Put like this to show only when user is logged in:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    show_admin_bar(true);
}
```

Answer (score 49):

Some custom wordpress theme doesn't show the admin bar into the theme page same with the wp_head() and the wp_footer() wrote on the templates files.
To resolve that problem just add the following code into your function.php or into your own plugin:

```
function admin_bar(){

  if(is_user_logged_in()){
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' , 1000 );
  }
}
add_action('init', 'admin_bar' );
```

Hope that help...

Comment: Your mention of wp_footer() made me check my footer template. It did not have a wp_footer() call. Simply adding that to the template made the admin bar appear again. Thanks!

Comment: This solution still works. Saw this 3 years ago and then today. Worked both times.

Answer (score 11):

If you had the bar showing previously, you might try this super-easy fix (worked for me):

1. Go to your profile in WP Admin
2. Check to see if "Show Toolbar when viewing site" is checked
3. If not, select this and save … that should fix it
4. If the option IS checked, deselect it and save. Then, select it again and save.

Now have another look at the frontend. I did this and it fixed whatever the issue was without messing with any of the files.

Comment: where can i find this setting? -> "Show Toolbar when viewing site"

Comment: @Nadia  the user settings from wordpress admin  wp-admin you can find USER -> all user ->  select related user  edit the user info you will find                 
                   https://prnt.sc/15yf3xu

Answer (score 8):

I have managed to make it appear again by adding

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

in "header.php" after `</header>` tag.

One important thing is to clear cache (**check if you have cache plugin for Wordpress installed like WP Super Cache or LiteSpeed Cache..**) and then CTRL + F5 to refresh page.

Comment: Ideally we call wp_footer() in the footer.php. But yes, this works anyway.

Comment: I use W3TC -- simply clearing all caches fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: it worked for me. weird that we need to call wp_footer() after the header so i added this before the closing body tag

Comment: I just forget to add wp_footer() to my index.php XD

Answer (score 3):

Try disable your plug-in cache or disable for logged-in users. I had similar problem using WP Fastest Cache. Just disabled chache for logged-in users and it's working.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing helped you, try to delete all cookies. It works.

Comment: Worked for me. Too late to check without more effort than I can spare now, but if anyone knows why this should affect things, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on our production site, but it was not occurring on local or staging sites.  Turns out that the WordPress Address was incorrectly set with www whereas the site was always accessed without the www.

The fix:

- Go to `settings` > `General`
- Ensure that `WordPress Address` and `Site Address` both match your site URL exactly

Posting in case anyone else has same problem.

Comment: This helped me, my site address was missing the 's' from https.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly: Most probably you have not logged in!
Long answer:
This problem happens to the new WordPress learners who try to create a custom theme. They put the `wp_footer()` and `wp_head()` functions and refresh and still do not see the admin bar. And it is because they have forgot to log in to `/wp-admin/`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing php extensions curl and intl
but above all php-curl

Answer (score 0):

I am using WP Super Cache, and what worked for me was disabling this option in
**WP Super Cache Settings / Advanced / Cache Restrictions**:

Make known users anonymous so they’re served supercached static files.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the wp-config.php file in your root directory, set

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

to

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

and go to the webpage where admin bar is not loading. There has to be some error in you php code.

The problem is that admin bar loads in wp_footer hook or something, and if you have an error in you php code the page just stops loading and that's why admin bar is not showing **AND THAT'S WHY ADDING WP_FOOTER() TO "header.php" WORKS FINE**.

Better check errors, because you probably will get another funny things on your website later.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
function show_admin_bar_forcefully() {
    return true;
}
add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'show_admin_bar_forcefully' , 999999);

/* Apply this code in your function.php and make sure not apply css in backend */
```